# how write update and inner query for multiple records in msql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below mysql query which is working fine for single record

```
UPDATE userstable
    SET LIKECOUNT = (SELECT SUM(LIKECOUNT) 
                     FROM topicstable
                     WHERE USERID = '11'
                   )
    WHERE USERID = '11';
```

i have  10000 records in "userstable" and i want to perofrm the above query to all of them.

How should i do it in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE userstable u
    SET LIKECOUNT = (SELECT SUM(LIKECOUNT) 
                     FROM topicstable t
                     WHERE t.USERID = u.USERID
                   );
```